# Как получить структуру с размером кратным 16-и?

Tags: c++

Есть ли способ выравнять размер структуры кратно определенному значению? С помощью дополнительных байтов к конце структуры или между её полями.

Пока делаю так:

```
#define PADDING(s, a)       uint8_t _padding_bytes[(((s + a - 1) / a) * a)]

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)

struct Foo
{
    int a;
};

union FooPadded
{
    Foo foo;
    PADDING(sizeof(Foo), 16);
};

#pragma pack(pop)
```

### update

В идеале получить универсальное решение, в том числе для компиляторов, не поддерживающих c++11, для моего конкретного случая требуется поддержка MSVC2010 и armcc5.1.

Comment: Вам нужно выравнивание или заполнение/упаковка? Код в вопросе отличается от самого вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос, как получить структуру, с размером, кратным 16-ти. Приведенный код делает это за счет поля `_padding_bytes`, размер которого вычисляется через макрос `PADDING`.

Answer (score 8):

Используйте `#pragma pack(16)`. Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
#pragma pack(push, 16)
struct Foo {
    int a;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Если используется **GCC**, то выравнивание можно задать следующим образом:

```
struct Foo { 
    int a; 
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

**UPD** (на комментарий 1).
С использованием `pack`, да - выравниваются адреса. А с использованием `__attribute__` - размер структуры будет равен 16. [Пример](https://ideone.com/aczgKo) использования.

**UPD** (на комментарий 2).
Это верное замечание, но `__attribute__` в **VS** уже не прокатит.

**UPD**
В **VS** можно попробовать такой вариант:

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct Foo {
   int a;
};
```

В **VS2015**, поскольку он поддерживает стандарт C++11 можно ещё и так

```
struct alignas(16) Foo {    
    int a;
};
```

Кстати последний вариант работает и в **GCC**. Вот [проверка](https://ideone.com/mMFWTX).

Comment: Насколько понимаю, здесь компилятор только выравняет адрес поля **a**, кратно 16-ти, размер структуры останется равным sizeof(int).

Comment: Первый вариант будет работать и в GCC. Чисто для заметки. Сделали "обратную совместимость" с MSVC

Comment: @VladimirGamalian первый вариант - да. Второй будет работать честно: http://ideone.com/dAgyLp. Для MSVC нужно будет отдельно копаться в MSDN, например: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/83ythb65.aspx

Comment: @Embedder, обновил свой коммент, привёл ссылочку для VS

Comment: Все варианты (кроме первого `#pragma pack(push, 16)`, который не выравнивает размер), имеют эффект выравнивания начала структуры в памяти, что не позволяет использовать эти структуры в других структурах без нарушения упаковки.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, поясните пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду под "_не позволяет использовать эти структуры в других структурах без нарушения упаковки_". Просто не совсем понятна конечная цель.

Comment: Например если её вставить в другую структуру, которая уже содержит 1 байт, то общий размер вместо 17, будет 32

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, ну тогда можно комбинировать, например [так](https://ideone.com/KqGnNl)

Comment: К сожалению в MSVC2010 не работает (с использованием `__declspec(align(16))`) (комбинирование)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, к сожалению на MSVC2010 проверить не могу. У меня GCC и  [Visual C++ Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=48159). Хотя [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/83ythb65(v=vs.100).aspx)  говорит что `__declspec(align(#))` должен работать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39283/discussion-between-embedder-and-vladimir-gamalian).